# How do you parse any datatype in a text file followed by unwanted text in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I want to parse a text file which has entries in the following format..

```
From: 9822012345
To: 9823098230, 9811098123
Timestamp: 1363478914
TID: T4
Message Text: What is Rajanikanth's gmail address? gmail@rajanikanth.com!
```

I want to parse it such that `9822012345` goes to an long integer, but i want to ignore the `from :` and the numbers in `To:` goes to array of long integers, `timestamp` to a long integer, `TID` to a string and message text to string ? but i want to leave out string values from, to timestamp,tid,message text. How do I go about it?

Comment: There is no special shortcut. You can use something like `strtok()` but it might be just as easy to scan the lines for the colon, strip out spaces, and then convert the digits to a number. Not sure what else you wanted to hear.

Comment: You should post the code you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `std::ifstream::getline`, `sscanf`, and `strtok` is sufficient to read the input data and process them.

Here's a working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char const* inputFile = "myinput.txt";
   ifstream in(inputFile);
   if ( !in )
   {
      return 1;
   }

   unsigned long fromNumber;
   std::vector<unsigned long> toNumbers;
   unsigned long timeStamp;
   std::string TID;
   std::string messagString;

   char line[256];
   while ( !in.getline(line, 255).eof() )
   {
      string field1 = strtok(line, ":");
      char* field2 = strtok(NULL, "\n");
      if ( field1 == "From" )
      {
         sscanf(field2, "%ld", &fromNumber);
      }
      else if ( field1 == "To")
      {
         char* field3 = strtok(field2, ",");
         while ( field3 )
         {
            unsigned long number = 0;
            sscanf(field3, "%ld", &number);
            toNumbers.push_back(number);
            field3 = strtok(NULL, " ");
         }
      }
      else if ( field1 == "Timestamp" )
      {
         sscanf(field2, "%ld", &timeStamp);
      }
      else if ( field1 == "TID" )
      {
         TID = field2;
      }
      else if ( field1 == "Message Text")
      {
         messagString = field2;
      }
   }

   // Print the data we read to make sure that nothing went wrong.
   cout << "From: " << fromNumber << endl;
   cout << "To: ";
   std::vector<unsigned long>::iterator iter = toNumbers.begin();
   std::vector<unsigned long>::iterator end = toNumbers.end();
   for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
   {
      cout << *iter << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
   cout << "Timestamp: " << timeStamp << endl;
   cout << "TID:" << TID << endl;
   cout << "Message Text:" << messagString << endl;
}
```

I put your data in `myinput.txt`. Here's the output of the program:

```
From: 9822012345
To: 9823098230 9811098123 
Timestamp: 1363478914
TID: T4
Message Text: What is Rajanikanth's gmail address? gmail@rajanikanth.com!
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not too difficult to parse this text.
Just read one line at once, then seek and ignore the characters until you find a colon (:) in a reading line. After finding colon, read and store characters, ignore white spaces if it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to search for the ':' and split the str. I guess once you know the tag you probably can process what you find after it in different ways.

I'll assume you can get the line from the file, we'll call it 'lineStr'

```
char *rhs = strchr(lineStr, ':');
*rhs = NULL;    // instert a null, overwriting the ':'
rhs++;          // advance the ptr to just after the ':'
```

Now 'linestr' will contain everything up to the ':'
and 'rhs' will contain everyting after the ':'